# Libreoffice equivalent to MS Excel TABLE

Tags: libreoffice

Im new toLibreoffice and I'm looking for something similar to a EXCEL TABLE, which allows you to autofill formulas in a column without having to do it yourself.

Any answer is appreciatted. Tx.

Comment: You might be better off asking this on http://ask.libreoffice.org/... once it's online :/

Comment: OP should still be able to ask [here](http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/Users-f1639498.html).

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice Calc has a facility called `Autofill`.

Let's say you have a column with the header cell, `A1`, called `Column A`. Cell `A2` has `a001`, cell `A3` has `a002`, cell `A4` has `a003`.

Select cells `A2` downwards for as much as you need. Then Click on Edit, Fill, Series, to open a window which has the Autofill option.

Note that the filled cells you include in the selected area must have a pattern that Calc can recognize as some sort of pattern to autofill.

Answer (score 0):

[Tools For Calc Edit](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/tools-for-calc-edit) extension propagate cell content down until it meet non-empty cell.